# C++ Dividing 0 without errors

Tags: c++

I actually need to divide by zero for something I am creating. It does not push the 0 towards my program. But instead pushes the equation to another. Is there anyway possible I can divide by zero without running into an error?

Comment: No, since the division by 0 is undefined.  There is no result you could forward.

Comment: Divide what by zero? An integer or a real?

Comment: Test for `0` and set the answer to what you conciser reasonable

Comment: send them as characters and parse it out on the other end?

Comment: Thanks for help. Got it solved!

Comment: @Nathan In the case of real numbers you could return INF.

Comment: [Expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) is the correct answer ;) Other symbolic computation methods may also work